# Why a series diode for the mosfets in this circuit?

Tags: mosfet

Whats the reason for the diodes on those two mosfets in the inverter?[image]

Link: http://inductionheatertutorial.com/inductionheater/inductionschematic.gif

Comment: Are you talking about `D3` and `D4`? There's a lot of diodes here.

Comment: You should include the circuit image directly in the post in case the link breaks

Comment: only D3 they are marked the same.

Comment: to be fair, they are marked very poorly, im talking about the ones going into the drain of the two power mosfets.

Comment: So which designators are you talking about? Sometimes you end up paralleling diodes if your body diode in the MOSFET is too slow. Have you compared the datasheets?

Comment: im not talking about the paralleling diodes, im talking about the two 65pq015 diodes in series.

Comment: @winny I don't think that edit really helped because of StackExchange's picture size limit. I still have the link [to the original picture](http://inductionheatertutorial.com/inductionheater/inductionschematic.gif). The original picture is larger and much easier to read.

Comment: Please refer them by their designators. If you add parallel diodes which are faster, you may need to block out the body diodes with external (normally schottky) diodes. It’s unusual but not unheard of. I used that on my SSTC.

Comment: @KingDuken I can zoom to the full resolution. You can’t?

Comment: Even at full resolution that is a mess!

Comment: @winny Huh... Interesting... I was expecting lossy behavior if you zoomed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The MOSFETs have very slow (circa 1 us reverse recovery) bulk diodes so putting a schottky diode (65PQ015) in series with the drain stops the slow reverse recovery playing a role but, you do need diodes so the MUR1560s do this job and they have a reverse recovery of 60 ns. It's probably all about getting a few percent more efficiency from the half bridge when it drives the load induction coil.

Comment: That’s what I said! :-)

Comment: @winny so you did. No plagiarism intended dear chap. Honest I was looking at data sheets and not comments!

Comment: No worries mate :-)